# JUnit and Mockito unit test for stream.mark(stream.available) when doing S3 putObject

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have a method which puts InputStream in s3 bucket.

```
@Override
    public String putObject(@NonNull String s3BucketName, @NonNull String s3Key, @NonNull String content,
                            @NonNull ObjectMetadata metadataRequest) {
        InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(content.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        try {
            stream.mark(stream.available());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            String errorMessage = String.format("Runtime error while marking stream.",
                    s3BucketName, s3Key);
            throw new RuntimeException(errorMessage, e);
        }
        PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest(s3BucketName, s3Key, stream, metadataRequest);
        return putObject(request);
    }
```

I want to make the method cause IOException and then throw RuntimeException and I have written the unit test for the same.

```
@Test
    public void putObjectTest_withStringContent_withMetadataRequest_IOError() {
        ObjectMetadata metadataRequest = new ObjectMetadata();
        metadataRequest.addUserMetadata(TEST_METADATA_KEY, TEST_METADATA_VALUE);
        InputStream mockStream = Mockito.mock(InputStream.class);
        Mockito.when(mockStream.mark(mockStream.available())).thenThrow(IOException.class);

        assertThrows(RuntimeException.class, () -> s3Accessor.putObject
                (TEST_S3BUCKET, TEST_S3OBJECT, TEST_STRING, metadataRequest));
    }
```

This is what I have tried but this is showing error in editor

```
Required type:
T
Provided:
void
reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that void conforms to T
```

How can I make the method throw IOException?

Comment: Your code is overly complex - why don't you just upload the string? What version of the SDK are you using? [`putObject(String bucketName, String key, String content)`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3.html#putObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) exists - no need to convert to a Stream. And even if you wanted to, there's no need to mark the stream.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary link to S3 doc - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/PutObjectRequest.html#PutObjectRequest-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.io.InputStream-com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ObjectMetadata-

Comment: Yes I'm aware - what are you setting in the object metadata specifically? Do you need it?

Comment: yes there is a user defined metadata that I need to add to the object

Comment: You can't mock a method's local variable. Even if the mocking would not cause a compiler error (see Ermiya Eskandary's anwer for a solution), you're not using that mock anywhere. It's never called anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stream.mark(...)` will [never throw any checked exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html#mark(int)) anyway so this is rather pointless.

You also don't need to mark or reset the stream manually at all. The SDK does that [behind the scenes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/best-practices.html#s3).

> By default, **the AWS SDK for Java attempts** to retry failed transfers by **marking** the input stream before the start of a transfer and then **resetting** it before retrying.

If your stream is larger than 128 KB, then you may need to call `setReadLimit` to 1 byte greater than the size of the stream to avoid a `ResetException` when not using a `FileInputStream`. If it isn't, then you don't need to do anything. Regardless, you don't need to mark or reset the stream yourself.

However, for reference purposes, `Mockito.when(...).thenThrow(...)` is for method invocations that return a value.

`stream.mark(mockStream.available())` is a method invocation that does **not** return a value (void return type).

As per [docs](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/4.5.1/org/mockito/Mockito.html#12):

> Use **doThrow()** when you want to stub the void method with an exception.

In this case, replace:

```java
Mockito.when(mockStream.mark(mockStream.available())).thenThrow(IOException.class);
```

With:

```java
doThrow(IOException.class).when(mockStream).mark(mockStream.available());
```

Comment: Thank you for this. 
**You also don't need to mark the stream 99% of the time so not sure why you're doing that.**
Can you please share some reasons why we don't need to mark the stream? The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/best-practices.html) mentions otherwise in best practices.

Comment: You're welcome - the SDK will do it for you. You just need to do `setReadLimit` (out of scope of this question) to 1 byte greater than the size of the stream (which you should know as you can get the size of `content.getBytes(...)`). If your string is smaller than 128 KB, then you don't even need to do `setReadLimit`.

Answer (score 0):

`stream` is a `ByteArrayInputStream`. That will never ever ever throw any exception when [mark](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html#mark(int)) is called. The documentation clearly states that no `IOException` can be thrown, and that the argument is ignored.

The exception doesn't come from the `mark` call, it comes from the `available` call. As the argument is ignored, just replace it with 0, and you don't need to catch the `IOException`. In fact, you'll get a compiler error:

> exception java.io.IOException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement